# Using tab delimiter in Cut in Unix Shell Scripting

Tags: shell-script, echo, cut

I have file `input.txt` with below data in TAB delimited format-

```
23776112        Inactive        Active
23415312        Inactive        Active
```

As per requirement, Inside the while loop, I want to use cut 1st column's data and print it -

Below is the part of code-

```
......
......
    while read line
    do  
        SN=`echo ${line}|cut -d '       ' -f1`
        echo $SN
    done < input.txt
....
....
```

To use the tab as delimiter above, I am using <kbd>Ctrl V</kbd> <kbd>Tab</kbd>

But the output is not as expected.I am getting O/P-

```
23776112 Inactive Active
23415312 Inactive Active
```

Whereas I want O/P like -

> ```
> 23776112 
> 23415312
> ```

Comment: no need to over complicate things, `cut -f1 input.txt` should be enough

Comment: @Q23 Note that the accepted answer there is far too complicated.

Comment: Yes, It is working, but I need to use it inside while loop as per complete program requirement.

Comment: @PraveenVerma This is seldom needed.  How do you need to use it? What do you want to do with it. It is quite possible that it's doable without a fragile shell loop.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
cut -f 1 input.txt
```

This gives you the first column from the tab-delimited file `input.txt`.  The default field delimiter for `cut` is the tab character, so there's no need to further specify this.

If the delimiter is *actually* a space, use

```
cut -d ' ' -f 1 input.txt
```

If it turns out that there are *multiple* tabs and/or spaces, use `awk`:

```
awk '{ print $1 }' input.txt
```

The shell loop is not necessary for this operation, regardless of whether you use `cut` or `awk`.

See also "[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)".

---

The reason your script does not work is because the tab disappears when you `echo` the unquoted variable.

Related:

- [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)
- [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Tab</kbd> is the default separator for `cut`, you don't need an explicit argument for it.

However, you need to quote your variable to prevent the tabs from being turned into space.

```
SN=`echo "${line}"|cut -f1`
```

But you can also avoid using `cut` in the first place. Just set `IFS` to `\t`.

```
IFS=$'\t'
while read -r SN rest
do 
    echo "$SN"
done < input.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

bash interprets

```
$'\t'
```

as tabulator, so

```
cut -d $'\t' -f 1
```

is the way to tell `cut` to use the tabulator as seperator (which, however, is redunant, as it is default). However, I would prefer awk with the same syntax:

```
awk -v FS=$'\t' '{ print $1 }' < input.txt
```

Comment: TAB is the default separator for `cut`, you don't need to use `-d $'\t'`

Comment: @Barmar Of course, you are right. I added this as remark.

Comment: `awk` automatically splits on spaces or tabs, so `-F` is not needed in this particular case :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda `awk` takes *any* space by default, so `abc def` will also be split apart, which may not be wanted.

Comment: I know. In this particular case, the fields seems to be space free though.

Comment: @Kusalananda Perhaps, but the question repeatedly mentions Tab specifically, so it seems wrong to ignore that detail and allow any whitespace as a delimiter.